# DotVVM Datepicker manual input

Tags: dotvvm

I'm trying the datepicker with bootstrap control in DotVVM just like what the documentation said. https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/4.0/controls/businesspack/DatePicker
In the said example, it was allowing the user to input a date manually, but when I tried applying in the project, it still not allowing to input manually, but rather a popup calendar.

`<bs:DateTimePicker SelectedDate="{value: DateFilter}" Mode="Date" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy" />`

[image]